# How to add parameters in service call for @RequestParam backend?

Tags: java, angular, query-string, http-parameters

If i have something like

```
@GetMapping(value = "/list")
public ResponseEntity<MyDTO> findStatusPerEC(@RequestParam final List<Long> numbersEC)
```

How do I add numbersEC in my url on the frontend? Is this query parameter?

I know this one was for old call that didn´t had query parameters and data was only a number (long)

```
return this.http.get<any>(URL_API + '/simulator/status/' + data);
```

But now I have to send a list of long values...may you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
return this.http.get<any>(URL_API + '/simulator/status/' + data);
```

Since you mentioned `data` is only a `long` type, what you are referring to here when you make the above request is a **PathVariable** it is slightly different to a **RequestParam**.

- Path variables have the syntax: `/simulator/status/:statusID` where statusID is dynamic and extracts values from the URI.
- Request parameters have the syntax: `?arg=val&arg2=val2` etc... and extract values from the request query string.

#### Solution

To answer your question,  to send an array across as request parameters, you can do it like so:

`?myparam=myValue1&myparam=myValue2&myparam=myValue3`

As you can see, above `myparam` is unchanging, and the values are variable, hence the data within your list data structure.

So when you're making your request it will look similar to this:

**Angular/Javascript**

```js
return this.http.get<any>(URL_API + '/list' + '?myparam=myValue1&myparam=myValue2&myparam=myValue3');
```

**Java**

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/list")
public ResponseEntity<MyDTO> findStatusPerEC(@RequestParam final List<Long> numbersEC)
```

I hope this helps.